# Config or operational data from pyang confd

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, confd

Can we determine if it is a configuration or operational data model from the pyang model in confD, If I do not have permission to read the actual yang file
Eg:

```
module: my-test
  +--rw something
     +--rw leaf1?      string
     +--rw leaf2?      string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [FAQ](https://www.tail-f.com/confd-faq/) A data-model defines the configuration (R-W) data, operational (R-O) data, and administrative actions that are accessible for a management system and maintained by the device.

From Pyang file, rw indicates configuration data while ro indicate read/operational data

Eg:

```
module: optest

    +--ro optable
       +--ro opname?      string
       +--ro opvalue?   string
```